# Crear lienzos dinámicos fabric Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Hola buenas queria saber si es posible crear lienzos dinámicos en canvas, ya que en una misma vista puedo tener varias zonas de lienzo ejp(corazón, frontal, espalda), lo que hago es que itero las zonas que tengo en botones y según pulso un botón cargo la información de ese producto con AJAX, pero al ser todos la misma `id` pues no reconoce ninguno.

**Aquí imprimo los resultados**

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);top: 50%; position: relative; bottom: 0%; display: contents;" id="posicionProducto">                   
     /* Resultados  */               
</div>
```

**Primero itero las zonas que tiene un producto**

```
@foreach ($zonas as $item)
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="{{ $item->id }}" class="btn btnVer cambiar_zona">{{ $item->name_zona }}</a>
@endforeach
```

**Luego según el botón que pulso consulto con AJAX a la base de datos:**

```
$(function()
    {
      $(document).on('click', '.cambiar_zona', function()
      {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var informacion = 'id=' + id;
        let url = '/admin/catalogo/extraer-producto/' + id;
        
            $.ajax({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
                type: "get",
                url: url,
                data: informacion,
                success: function(data){
                    $('#posicionProducto').empty();
                    $('#posicionProducto').append('<div style="position: relative">\
                                                        <img src="'+ data.zonas.foto +'" alt="" id="img_producto" style="width: 100%;">\
                                                        <div style="position: absolute; top: '+ data.zonas.position_top +'%; left: '+ data.zonas.position_left +'%; width: '+ data.zonas.width +'%; height: '+ data.zonas.height +'%;">\
                                                            <canvas id="c_'+ data.zonas.id +'" style="border-color: '+ data.zonas.borde +';"></canvas>\
                                                        </div>\
                                                   </div>');
                                            **Luego se crea el lienzo**
                                           var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(document.getElementById('c'+ data.zonas.id +''));
                                           canvas.setWidth($('.canvas-container').width());
                                          canvas.setHeight($('.canvas-container').height())
                }
            });
      
        });
    });
```

Pero claro está asociado a la id `c` y ser repite por tantas iteraciones haya. Esto puede ser de alguna manera dinámico? Saludos

He probado a dejar una sola zona, para que solo tenga una id, pero tampoco funciona, así que supongo que no tiene acceso la respuesta del AJAX al JavaScript

**Actualización - IMPORTANTE**

He conseguido que funcione metiendo las funciones de crear el lienzo en la respuesta del AJAX, y ahora si carga bien los lienzos con una ID asociada. Pero claro cada vez que cambio entre zonas, se me borran los demás lienzos.

Por cada zona genero un botón, y por AJAX según al botón que le de me carga una zona con su foto y lienzo, pero al ir pasado de una a otra me borra la anterior. Se tienen que quedar guardadas pero solo verse la que tengo activa, se que es por esto: `$('#posicionProducto').empty();` pero si no pongo esto, por cada pulsación en el botón de una zona me pone todas y nos se ocultan.

Comment: Ese "luego se crea el lienzo" no es muy clarificador. ¿Dónde está ese código?¿se llama al obtener la respuesta de la llamada AJAX?¿Podrías pasarle como parámetro la ID que quieres usar en cada iteración?

Comment: Hola @PabloLozano lo de luego se crea el lienzo lo muevo a la respuesta del AJAX, con eso consigo que se cree el lienzo con la id del producto, así siempre son diferentes. El problema que me encuentro es que cada vez que cambio de zona y se crea un lienzo nuevo el otro se elimina. Por ejemplo, puede tener parte del/tra de una camiseta, si cambio entre vistas no se tiene que borrar

Answer (score 1):

se puede generar lienzos de Canvas dinámicamente de la manera que estás haciendo. Si entiendo bien, cada vez que haces clic en un botón, solicitas información de la zona correspondiente a través de AJAX, y luego creas un lienzo Canvas en esa zona específica.

Entiendo que tienes problemas con la eliminación de lienzos anteriores cuando cambias entre zonas. La razón de esto es que estás vaciando el contenedor #posicionProducto cada vez que se hace clic en un botón.

Lo que necesitas es mantener los lienzos existentes y solo mostrar el que está activo. Para hacer eso, puedes modificar un poco tu lógica:

1. En lugar de eliminar todo el contenido de #posicionProducto, podrías
   ocultar todos los lienzos y luego solo mostrar el que corresponde a
   la zona activa.
2. Para hacer esto, puedes darle una clase común a todos los lienzos
   (como canvas-zona) y usarla para seleccionar y ocultar todos los
   lienzos.
3. Luego, puedes seleccionar y mostrar solo el lienzo que corresponde a
   la zona activa.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cambiar_zona', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var informacion = 'id=' + id;
  let url = '/admin/catalogo/extraer-producto/' + id;
  
  $.ajax({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
    type: "get",
    url: url,
    data: informacion,
    success: function(data){
      // Oculta todos los lienzos
      $('.canvas-zona').hide();

      // Verifica si el lienzo ya existe
      if ($('#c_'+ data.zonas.id).length > 0) {
        // Si el lienzo ya existe, simplemente muéstralo
        $('#c_'+ data.zonas.id).show();
      } else {
        // Si el lienzo no existe, créalo
        $('#posicionProducto').append('<div class="canvas-zona" style="position: relative">\
                                          <img src="'+ data.zonas.foto +'" alt="" id="img_producto" style="width: 100%;">\
                                          <div style="position: absolute; top: '+ data.zonas.position_top +'%; left: '+ data.zonas.position_left +'%; width: '+ data.zonas.width +'%; height: '+ data.zonas.height +'%;">\
                                              <canvas id="c_'+ data.zonas.id +'" style="border-color: '+ data.zonas.borde +';"></canvas>\
                                          </div>\
                                     </div>');
                                      
        // Crea el lienzo
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c_'+ data.zonas.id);
        canvas.setWidth($('.canvas-container').width());
        canvas.setHeight($('.canvas-container').height());
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Este código es similar al tuyo, pero agrega una verificación para ver si el lienzo ya existe. Si el lienzo existe, simplemente lo muestra; si no existe, lo crea. Esto debería evitar que los lienzos anteriores se eliminen cuando cambies entre zonas.